# How to access previous ng-repeat element in an ordered array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to compare the previous element in a ng-repeat that is ordered to the current one. If the two appointments have the same DateString I don't want it to print out. You can see I try to prevent that in the ng-if.

```
<div ng-repeat="appointment in appointments | orderBy: 'milliSeconds' " ng-if="!noAppointments">
                <div class="row row-date" ng-if="appointments[$index - 1].DateString != appointment.DateString">
                    <div class="col">
                        {{appointment.DateString}}
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
```

This does not work though. Do you guys have any suggestions on how this could be done?

Comment: Maybe just change `"appointment in appointments | orderBy: 'milliSeconds' track by $index"` but I'm not sure how this could handle the first value where `[$index - 1]` will be `[-1]`. Anyway I think this is not the correct way to deal with this kind of problems, the logic should stay in the controller and not in the view. Probably you should use a `foreach` on the `$scope.appointments` variable beforehand to set an `appointment.show` vraiable and use that in the `ng-if`

Comment: yeah I could just add if $index != 0 but that doesn't seem to cause the problem. This is sometimes false. I think its because orderBy doesn't actually change the order of the array where $index still only increments

Comment: @Naigel I tried moving the logic to the controller and ran into an issue. I'll go back and try to handle it there

Answer (score 0):

I sorted the array in the controller and moved the logic there too to solve this.